# Formula to show the highest value another cell ever reached

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cell with number A1, how create another cell (A2) with highest number of A1?
For example: A1 = 10 A2 = 10, then i change A1 to 20 A2 = 20, then i change A1 = 12 but A2 still 20.
It means if A1 greater than previous A1 it should be write to A2

Comment: Does **A1** change because it has a *formula* or does it have a *typed* value ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent A1 is sum of many values

Comment: Once A1 is calculated, copy the value (not the cell content, just the value), to another cell. Once there is a change, compare A1 to the value of that cell. (Keep out: first to the comparison and only then do the copy) Before I forget: you need VBA, no way you get this done using pure Excel formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely do that. The number you want to save is in cell A1. Place this formula in cell A2 intentionally creating a circular reference.

```
=IF(A1>A2,A1,A2)
```

You need to enable iterative calculation in File > Options > Formulas > Enable iterative calculation.

Anytime a number in A1 is higher, it will save that number. It will ignore numbers with lower value. It even saves the number when saved and reopened.

See the [example](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/15/circular-reference-excel/) of a timestamp using a circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    newval = Range("A1")

    If Range("A2") = "" Then
    Else
        If newval <= Range("A2") Then Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A2") = newval
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as *.xlsm* rather than *.xlsx*

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**